# How to make one object pass through the holes of another?

Tags: modeling, rigid-body-simulation

[image: image of connect4 piece not going in connect4 board]I'm making a connect4 animation, I've made all the pieces for it, and I'm using rigid body physics to simulate the piece dropping into the board, but it stops when it hits the top of the board, as shown in the picture. I've double checked the sizes to make sure the piece is smaller than the hole, I've also tried changing the collision margin like in this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187723/how-can-i-make-objects-go-through-holes), but i'm unsure where to go from there

for reference, the piece is an active-type rigid body while the board is a passive-type rigid body

Comment: I'd suggest you don't actually use the model of the connect four board as the actual collision. Instead make the dividers in between rows simple rectangles, same with the front and back of the board. This will help it be a lot more predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have your collision set to the default of 'Convex Hull' in the Rigid Body settings. Try changing to 'Mesh'.